# Teradata - Know the load volume by times of a table

Tags: sql, teradata

I have some tables in Teradata and I would like to know the variations of the table by sections of time.

In this tables I have a Timestamp type field that tells me the date / time of variation and a field where it tells me if it is update or insert. I would like to be able to make a grouping to see the variation every 15 minutes of the records in the period of the last 24 hours.

Example of the result that I need:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVzHg.png)

Can anyone give me ideas on how to do something like that or similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by the timestamp truncated to the quarter hour using

```
ts -cast(extract(minute from ts) mod 15 as interval minute)
   -cast(extract(second from ts) as interval second)
```

You can apply the same calculation to get the last 24 hours, e.g.

```
where ts >= 
   current_timestamp
      -cast(extract(minute from current_timestamp) mod 15 as interval minute)
      -cast(extract(second from current_timestamp) as interval second)
      -interval '1' day
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @dnoeth. It has been helpful